# Using collection select in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a simple blog application. In which each post can be associated with the tags. This is my view

**_form.hmtl.erb**

```
<%= form.collection_select(:tag_ids, @tags, :id, :name, {}, :multiple => true) %>
```

This is my controller

**posts_controller.rb**

```
 def new
    @post = @topic.posts.new
    @tag = @post.tags.new
    @tags = Tag.all
  end

  def create
    @post = @topic.posts.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to topic_posts_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title,:content,:post_image, tag_ids: [])
  end
end
```

Model **Post.rb**

```
 has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
```

I am getting an error while creating new post "NoMethodError in Posts#create", "undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass". I am not able to find where the error is.

Comment: are you getting `@tags` in the `_form` partial?

Comment: @Gabbar yes. I am using the partial form for both edit and create post

Comment: @are you using `acts_as_taggable` gem?

Comment: @Gabbar No I haven't used any for this.

Comment: Could you please add the `Post` model code? and is there any callback method in `Post` model?

Comment: @JunanChakma I have added Post model code

Comment: @GomathiN when do you get this error? i mean on submitting the form or on loading this new page?

Comment: @Gabbar While submitting the form. I think it is on create action and while calling post_params. But I don't know what is the reason

Comment: Did you check what are you getting of `post_params[:tag_ids]` in `Post#create` while creating a `Post`?

Comment: @JunanChakma This is what i am getting at "@post" of create  #<Post id: nil, topic_id: 12, user_id: nil, title: "sjjdhjshj", content: "jjxbcjxbcjx", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, post_image_file_name: nil, post_image_content_type: nil, post_image_file_size: nil, post_image_updated_at: nil>

Comment: @GomathiN could you try the modified answer given below and let me know for further guidance.thank you.

Comment: @GomathiN could you let me know if the modified answer below is working or not? feel free to accept answer, it it helped you, for future SO searcher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a join table with name `posts_tags.rb`

```
class Post_Tag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :post
end
```

so you have already some tags which you want to be selected with post and join table should be updated with `post_id` and `tag_id`

change this in your form_partial: -

```
<%= select_tag "tag_ids", options_for_select(@tags,:id,:name),{}, multiple: true%> <br/><br/>
```

Note: - you should not use `form.collection_select(:tag_ids...)` Reason being `form_for` is used here for `@post` object and `tag_ids` is not attribute of `@post` object.

so on submitting form you should get array of tag's ids in `params[:tag_ids]`

```
  def create
    @post = @topic.posts.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      #create join table for tags that are associated with post
      @post.tags << Tag.find(params[:tag_ids]) 
      redirect_to topic_posts_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

so here you can get

`@post.tags` =>  which will return you collection of tags associated with the post

Comment: I think Migration is enough for join table.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using this scenario you have to make MANY TO MANY relation between these two models.

> has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

then in form you should use like

> form.collection_select(:post, :tag_id, Tag.all, :id, :name_with_initial, prompt: true)

Comment: then you should see followings link https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

Answer (score 0):

The `@tags` variable is missing from your `create` action in controller - you have declared it in `new`, but not in `create`. It may cause error in view if save was unsucessful and action tries to re-render the form.

Not sure if that's all, because I'm not sure where the error is thrown exactly. But as you said in one of the comments - it works when you use `Tag.all` instead of `@tags`.

Comment: Yes When I create a @tags variable in create action it works fine but how?

Comment: Instance variables used in view need to be declared in controller action before renders. Error message was "undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass" - I guess at some point .collection_select needed to call .map on @tags and @tags wasn't there.